# UIImageView slides using Buttons

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimageview

I have a homework with which I'm stuck. Here it is:

*Make a gallery project: a large UIImageView and two buttons below it: Back and Next. Add 10 pictures to the project, and by clicking on the buttons, the previous or next picture should be displayed, respectively.*

So I made an array, and some *silly attempt* to go through this array. But i'm 100% sure that there is some simple answer to that. 

Thank you!

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var imagesIV: UIImageView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       }
    let images = [UIImage(named: "1"), UIImage(named: "2"), UIImage(named: "3"),UIImage(named: "4"),UIImage(named: "5"),UIImage(named: "6"),UIImage(named: "7"),UIImage(named: "8"),UIImage(named: "9"),UIImage(named: "10")]
    var numberOfImages = images.count
    var  currentImage = 0

    @IBAction func forwardButton(_ sender: Any) {
        guard case currentImage + 1 < images.count else {return}
        currentImage += 1
    }
    
    @IBAction func backButton(_ sender: Any) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does 'imagesIV' come into play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way in my opinion is below, specifically to make your code scalable (e.g. if you have 1000 photos, you don't want to add them manually one by one in the array):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var imagesIV: UIImageView!
    var  currentImageIndex = 0
    var images : [UIImage] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        for a in 1...10 {
            if let newImage = UIImage(named: "\(a)") {
                images.append(newImage)
            }
        }
        
        updateImageInImageView()
    }
    
    @IBAction func forwardButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if currentImageIndex + 1 != images.count { currentImageIndex += 1} else { currentImageIndex = 0}
        updateImageInImageView()
    }
    
    @IBAction func backButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if currentImageIndex != 0 { currentImageIndex -= 1} else { currentImageIndex = images.count - 1}
        updateImageInImageView()
    }
    
    func updateImageInImageView()  {
        imagesIV.image = images[currentImageIndex]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you! But may I ask some questions so I will better understand whats going on under the hood? In which part do we connect array to the UIImageView? How does the code know that we want it to put pictures there? And in this part "UIImage(named: "\(a)")" why did it upload all photos? "a" is some kind of universal placeholder? Thank you again and sorry for some extra questions!

Comment: Hello @KseniiaPiskun [In which part we connect array to UIImageView?] Image update is done via updateImageInImageView() function. [How does code know that we want it to put pictures there?] The updateImageInImageView() function is triggered once you hit either forwardButton or backButton.  [And in this part "UIImage(named: "(a)")" why did it upload all photos? "a" is some kind of universal placeholder?], no it is simple a loop that repeats it self 10 times, each time increasing the value of a by 1, and then concatenate the value to the image string, after which the new image is added to array

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
@IBAction func forwardButton(_ sender: Any) {
    guard currentImage + 1 < images.count else {return}
    currentImage += 1
    imagesIV.image = images[currentImage]
}

@IBAction func backButton(_ sender: Any) {
    guard currentImage - 1 >= 0  else {return}
    currentImage -= 1
    imagesIV.image = images[currentImage]
}
```